# How to interpret angle of Ellipse in drawing guide?

Tags: trigonometry, conic-sections

Im a designer who, in my work, often uses drawing guides for drawing ellipses. A few nights ago I attempted to design some guides of my own but I was baffled as a I could not understand how to define my ellipses in the same way they are defined on the standardized drawing guides. On these guides the ellipses are described by an angle that ranges from 90 (circular) to 0+ (0 is just a line)

In the picture below, you can see a drawing guide with ellipses described as "45 degrees". I drew some lines of top of them and you can clearly see that neither A, B or C is 45 degrees (blue line is 45).

Im sure this is very simple for you guys but I cannot figure out how it works,
thanks!

[image: image of 45 degree drawing guide]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably something related to the [angular eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_eccentricity) $\alpha$ of the ellipse. If your extremes of 0 and 90° are correct, it would be $90^\circ-\alpha$ rather than $\alpha$ itself.

This would correspond to the intersection between your blue 45° line and the major axis being the *focus* of the ellipse, and the angle is then the angle between the major axis and the line that connects the focus to the end of the minor axis.

This *also* matches n00b's description of the angle between the line-of-sight and the plane of a circle that is foreshortened by perspective to have the aspect ratio of the ellipse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Henning, is this the α you're referring to?pic: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FrJZQ.png

A follow up then: Will the foci shift as α -> 0 or will it remain in the same position on the major axis?

I guess I have to learn how to calculate the focus anyway

Comment: @DavidLamm: Yes. And also yes, the foci shift around on the major axis depending on the eccentricity. They coincide at the middle of the axis for a circle and move towards the ends the sorter the minor axis is.

Answer (score 4):

$30 *\sin(\pi/4) = 21.213$, it's a circle viewed from an angle of 45 degrees

Comment: That sounds right as that's what these guides are used for, drawing stuff in perspective. Although when using your equation and changing for example to pi/6, getting 30x15 as my measurements, I get this result:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/r3Eav.png

Comment: I measure those ellipses as having ratio 170:480, giving a viewing angle of $20^\circ$, odd, not sure what to suggest

Comment: @DavidLamm, I think your ellipse guide is labelled wrong. I held my 20 degree ellipse guide up to the monitor and it matches what yours is labelled as 30 degrees. Mine is made in the USA.

Answer (score 1):

If you think of a straight line parallel to the ground coming out from your eye and hitting a perpendicular piece of paper with a circle on it, you get a 90° angle. As you tilt the paper away from you, there's a bigger angle on the side closest to you, and a smaller angle on the other side of the paper. That's the angle of the ellipse, and when the paper is parallel with you sight line the angle has reached 0°.
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p51HN.jpg)

[It's kind of hard to see it but there's a perfect circle on the paper on the desk that from this angle (15°) looks the same as the 15° ellipse drawn on the post-it note which is perpendicular to the camera.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilR7x.jpg)

Not the most mathematical explanation, but probably the most practical for any artists/designers who end up here from google wondering the answer to this like me.